# Node startup failed with error: internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {} in Corda

Tags: web, nodes, blockchain, corda

Just now I started learning Corda and I am building my custom Cordapp. The nodes are being deployed properly but when I am trying to run the nodes in my custom cordapp they fail to start and closes. The logs and the error shown are given below:

```
*RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10048
E 13:15:07+0000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {}
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_1

81]*
```

My build.graddle file is given below-

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 10006
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10007
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10008")
            adminAddress("localhost:10048")
        }
        webPort 10009
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10010
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10011")
            adminAddress("localhost:10051")
        }
        webPort 10012
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR"
        p2pPort 10013
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10014")
            adminAddress("localhost:10054")
        }
        webPort 10015
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}

task runExampleClientRPCJava(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.example.client.ExampleClientRPC'
    args 'localhost:10008'
}
```

Comment: `pkill -9 java` in linux and `taskkill /f /im java.exe` on windows. there is some existing java process that's already using the port. just kill that process and start your nodes again

Comment: let me know if it solved the error. we can close this one then

Comment: I restarted everything and now its working fine. I think that was the issue of the port itself. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kill the process in linux using particular port: `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:{yourPortNumber})`

To kill process in windows using particular port:

Step 1) `netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber`

Step 2) `taskkill /PID PIDFromPrevious Step /F`